# Doctrine Many-to-Many relationship between three tables

Tags: php, doctrine, many-to-many

I have three tables: **note**, **user** and **tag**. Following is the diagram of the relationship between those tables:

[alt text http://www.ilabs.lt/share/database.jpg](http://www.ilabs.lt/share/database.jpg)

**User** can have many **Notes** and **Tags**, **Note** can have many **Users** and **Tags**, **Tag** can have many **Users** and many **Notes**. I have no problem setting many-to-many relationship between two tables, but can't manage to relate three tables. How can I describe this relationship in Doctrine?

Answer (score 1):

You should make NoteUserTag its own Record/Entity with an additional surrogate ID:

```
note_user_tag_id
note_id
user_id
tag_id
```

This is probably the best to handle this situation.